# What is the sum of a products of inverse elements from subsets of set $2^{A}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

We have set $A=\{1,...,n\}$ 
Let's consider set of subsets $2^{A}$ 
For each subset in $2^{A}$: $$B \in 2^{A}, P_{B}= \prod \limits _{b \in B} \frac{1}{b}$$
**Task:** Find the sum: $$\sum \limits _{B \in 2^{A}} P_{B} = \sum \limits _{B \in 2^{A}} \prod \limits _{b \in B} \frac{1}{b}$$

**My attempt:** 
Let's consider tuples of different lendth to figure out what is the general formula

1. Single sets $\{i\} \ \forall i \in A$ 
   $$P_{B} = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i} = H_{n} \quad \text{where} \ H_{n} \ \text{- harmonic number} $$
2. Pairs $\{i, j\} \ \forall i \neq j \in A $ 
   $$P_{B} = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i} \sum \limits_{j=1 \ j \neq i}^{n} \frac{1}{j} = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}\bigg[H_{n}\frac{1}{i} - \bigg(\frac{1}{i} \bigg)^{2} \bigg] = H_{n}^{2}-S_{n}^{2} \quad \text{where} \ S_{n}^{k} = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \bigg(\frac{1}{i}\bigg)^{k}$$
3. Triplets $\{i, j, k\} \ \forall i \neq j \neq k \in A$
   $$P_{B}=H_{n}^{3}-3H_{n}S_{n}^{2}+2S_{n}^{3}$$

Here it's hard to determine general formula and computations become complicated and it doesn't seem like and option to find a sum. 
Maybe is there some trick or may we use math expectation to compute that sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some advice for next time: try to calculate the answer for some small numbers. The pattern (in this case) is very easy to spot, and knowing what you want to show is very helpful when you're looking for a proof.

We prove that the sum is $n+1$ by induction. If $n=1$, we can just evaluate it.

For $n+1$, we know that all subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n+1\}$ either contain $n+1$ or don't. The sum of $P_A$ for the subsets $A$ which do not contain $n+1$ is $n+1$ by the induction hypothesis. And the sum of $P_B$ for the subsets $B$ containing $n+1$ is just $\frac{1}{n+1} (n+1) = 1$ since we can factor out the $\frac{1}{n+1}$ from the sum. Putting these together, the sum of $P_A$ for $A \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n+1\}$ is $n+2$, as we wanted.

Comment: Easy and beautiful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: But actually if n=1 the sum is 1 and f.e. if n=2, the sum $S=1+\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}$ both for two sets $\{1,2\}, \{2\}$. The same with n=3. So the answer should be edited a little bit.

Comment: I assume they take the [empty product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product) to be 1, so if $n=1$ the answer is actually $P_\emptyset + P_{\{1\}} = 1+\frac{1}{1}=2$.